# Windows 7 not genuine without Internet connection

Tags: windows-7

I bought Windows 7 the month it was released and I am very happy with it. But each time I have not internet connection in my home (due to technical difficulties at the ISP) Windows immediately claims not to be a legal copy. If Internet comes back, Windows is fine again. And I am sure I verified Windows several times by now.

But to be honest it is a bit annoying and a bit scary and I am sure this is not the way it should be.

I am planning to buy me a laptop computer for travel so I will not have an internet connection for days maybe. Will Windows always complain? One day without Internet makes it an illegal copy and it will cease to work properly?

Answer (score 6):

You can also activate by phone.

1. type `slui 4` in the search bar.
2. Click on the drop down menu and select the nearest location to you for a toll free number to call, then click on the Next button.
3. Call the activation phone number
4. the activation line is automated, so you will be asked to enter or speak the installation ID numbers displayed on your screen into the phone.
   NOTE The automated service will issue you a confirmation ID number. Have a pen and paper handy to write these numbers down.
5. Type in the confirmation ID number given to you to activate Windows 7, and click on Next.
6. When you get the Activation was successful window, click on Close to finish.

Comment: +1...Nice trick, learn something new every day..

Comment: I havent done this in a while, they might have changed it.  Based of what I have seen in the past, you will need a pen and paper, as they give you a LONG string of numbers to write down.